# Integrating AD with web application running on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, ldap

Am trying to change my web application using AD for authentication. My application uses Tomcat 5.5.17. Currently it uses UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users of the application. After reading many posts here, I used the following configuration in server.xml. (Since am just getting started, I didn't bother about roles).

But when I actually do try to login, i seem to get this error. (I used JXplorer to navigate through ActiveDirectory and hence I know that the URL works)

```
 javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/12/21 08:55:31 |   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3045)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/12/21 08:55:31 |   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2951)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/12/21 08:55:31 |   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2758)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/12/21 08:55:31 |   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1812)
```

Any ideas about where am getting it wrong?

Thanks
K

Comment: Could you post the configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. IF you are interested, I would welcome your comments on 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953317/legacy-application-with-jdbc-and-jndi-realm-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

I figured out that the ldap server that I was connecting to requires a binding user name and password, which when supplied it worked

For people who need it, here is how my config looks

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.CustomLdapUserRealm"
                    debug="99"
            userBase="ou=xx,ou=xx,ou=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx"
            userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
                    connectionURL="ldap://xxx:389"
                    digest="MD5"
                    roleName="cn"
                    roleBase="ou=xx,ou=xx,ou=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx"
                    userRoleName="xx" 
                    />
```

In CustomLdapUserRelam, i supplied the binding user name and password. Also in my web.xml i had to give permission to the roles that I would receive from LDAP