# LDAP authentication in Tomcat 7, how do I bind the LDAP in server.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, ldap, jndi

I am trying to get **LDAP authentication** using **Tomcat 7**.

I have the below configuration in my `server.xml`

```
     <Context path="/WebApp" reloadable="false" docBase="E:\ESS\Tomcat 7\webapps\WebApp">
          <ResourceLink name="mail/WebAPPMS" type="javax.mail.Session" global="mail_Session"/>
          <Manager checkInterval="60" debug="99"/>
          <ResourceLink name="jdbc/WebAppDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource" global="WebAppDataSource"/>
                  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99" connectionURL="ldap://company.com:3268" userBase="DC=company,DC=com" userSubtree="true" userSearch="(CN={0})"/>
          <ResourceLink name="directory/WebAppReports" type="java.lang.String" global="SchemaReportsDirectory"/>
    </Context>
```

Now in our **LDAP**, anonymous bind is not allowed. So I need to bind before searching and authenticating.

However, I cannot pass `connectionName`, `connectionPassword` and `userPassword`, since it would create authentication in `Comparison mode`, which is not allowed by **LDAP**.

Using the above config I am getting the following error:

> May 8, 2014 1:25:44 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm
>   authenticate SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
>   javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr:
>   DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a
>   successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece ];
>   remaining name 'DC=company,DC=com'    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUserBySearch(JNDIRealm.java:1446)
>     at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1297)
>     at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1194)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1052)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:573)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Which clearly means **LDAP** is not connected and I need to bind before authenticating.

After searching web, I found this, but I don't know how to create custom Realms:

[Integrating AD with web application running on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940777/integrating-ad-with-web-application-running-on-tomcat)

Comment: I don't know why they even have comparison mode. They don't need it. Just authenticate as the `connectionUser`, do the search, find the user, then rebind as that user, letting the LDAP server do the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

We posted here what we use for [Tomcat and LDAP](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP#section-Tomcat+And+LDAP-SecurityRealms)

BTW: You should never use comparison mode. Comparison of credentials usually by-passes security mechanisms within the LDAP Directory. Security mechanisms like intruder detection, expired passwords (and logins) etc may be by-passed.

Comment: I don't know why they even have comparison mode. They don't need it. Just authenticate as the `connectionUser`, do the search, find the user, then rebind as that user, letting the LDAP server do the authentication.